# Why CABasicAnimation will send the layer's view to back and front?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

There are two UIViews of similar size. UIView one (A) is originally on top of UIView two (B). When I try to perform a CABasicAnimation `transform.rotation.y` on A's layer:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
CGFloat startValue = 0.0;
CGFloat endValue = M_PI;
rotateAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:startValue];
rotateAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:endValue];
rotateAnimation.duration = 5.0;
[CATransaction begin];
[imageA.layer addAnimation:rotateAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

During the animation, the animating layer's UIView (A) will be:

1. sent back (A is suddenly behind B)
2. rotating ... passed second half of the animation
3. sent front (A is now on top of B again)

Is there a way to keep A on top of B for the whole animation period? Thanks!

UPDATE: project source is attached: [FlipLayer.zip](http://clomputing.com/temp/FlipLayer.zip)

Comment: BTW, the `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]` calls in your implementation of `-flip` are unnecessary. If you leave them out, you'll get an implicit transaction anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is a rotation around the Y axis will, in a true 3D compositing system, make layer A intersect with layer B, such that half of layer A should be visible and half should be behind layer B. CoreAnimation does not provide a true 3D compositing system. Instead it attempts to determine which layer is in front of which other layer, and renders it entirely without intersection. In your case, during the first half of the rotation CoreAnimation has decided that layer B is on top of layer A in the 3D space. The simplest solution is probably to set the zPosition of layer A to `layer.bounds.size.width` (default is 0) for the duration of the animation (or permanently, if it should always be on top).

If you want to set it only for the duration of the animation, you can add a second animation for the `transform.translation.z` key path. Here's your `-flip` method modified to use this:

```
- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
    CGFloat startValue = 0.0;
    CGFloat endValue = M_PI;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:startValue];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:endValue];
    animation.duration = 5.0;
    [imageOne.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotate"];
    animation.keyPath = @"transform.translation.z";
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageOne.layer.bounds.size.width];
    animation.toValue = animation.fromValue;
    [imageOne.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"zPosition"];
}
```

Comment: I tried to change `zPosition` with success. Please refer to attached source project for details.

Comment: Setting the zPosition to something absurd like `CGFLOAT_MAX` works.

Comment: Experimentally, it seems that setting it to `layer.bounds.size.width` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageA];` in your animation sequence?

Comment: imageA is on top before animation starts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to translate on the z axis and bring A forward first. Perform the rotation and then set the z back to its starting value.

Also, you probably won't see any perspective on the rotation unless you set the .m34 property on the transform. Try something like this:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0f / -300.0f;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0.0f, M_PI, 0.0f);

CABasicAnimation *rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation 
                                          animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
rotateAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue 
                                 valueWithCATransform3D(CATransformIdentity)];
rotateAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D(transform)];
rotateAnimation.duration = 5.0;

[imageA.layer addAnimation:rotateAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
```

You transaction block is unnecessary.

Best Regards.

Comment: `transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0.0f, M_PI, 0.0f);` causes an `error: too few arguments to function 'CATransform3DRotate'`